# How to console log value from an asset? in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am writing a network by hyperledger composer playground.

Here i have an asset called **patient**, and **patient** has list of **hospitals**, 
i have a transaction named **GetPatientHospitals** which is used to call the function **getPatientHospitals**, I want this function to print out a list of the ids (the thing like *resource:org.acme.patientchain.PatientHospital#5wyjftthjr* when i test), 
but when i test my function, it only told me my transaction has been submitted, no where i could see the output, is there any way to do it? or I need another asset to store these messages?

My   **getPatientHospitals** function:

```
function getPatientHospitals(gethospitals){
    return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.patientchain.Patient')
         .then(function (PatientAssetRegistry) {
    // Get the patient asset
        return  PatientAssetRegistry.get(gethospitals.patient.pubKeyPatient);
     })
  .then(function (patienthospital) {
    return patienthospital.hospitals;
  })
} //list of hospitals
```

My **GetPatientHospitals** transaction and **Patient** asset:

```
transaction GetPatientHospitals { 
--> Patient patient
}



asset Patient identified by pubKeyPatient {
 o String pubKeyPatient 
--> PatientHospital[] hospitals
```

}

This is the hospitals in a patient I tested:

```
{
  "$class": "org.acme.patientchain.Patient",
  "pubKeyPatient": "1652",
  "hospitals": [
    "resource:org.acme.patientchain.PatientHospital#5wyjftthjr",
    "resource:org.acme.patientchain.PatientHospital#mgnl6ag4vh",
    "resource:org.acme.patientchain.PatientHospital#5wyjftthjr"
  ]
}
```

I want to print those recourses or just the id after the ***#***

but there was no anywhere i could see the output, can I do "print" in this playground?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `console.log()` inside your js file. Then you can see the output in the browser developer console. For Firefox and Chrome you can show the developer console with *CTRL-SHIFT-I*. 
This works only if you are using Playground with a 'Web' profile, then you will see console.log output in the Browser Console. If you use Playground connected to a local Fabric instance, then the console.log output will be in the log of the Chaincode container.

Try with `console.log(patienthospital.hospitals)` and check the output in the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

For print the value you need to make one transaction in `cto` file.

Hyperledger composer provides **Transaction processor functions**. It can optionally return data to client applications. This can be useful for returning a receipt to the submitter of the transaction or returning an asset modified by the transaction to avoid a separate lookup of the **asset** after the transaction has been committed. Data can also be returned to the client application via a transaction **REST API** for the business network.

I recommend you to follow the below links :

1. [returning data from transaction processor function](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts)
2. [composer github](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4165)

Hope it will help you :)